# Using linq on a SharePoint list object

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint

I have a C# variable which references a SharePoint list.

I need to iterate over each list item and do a conditional check.

I would like to use a linq call to filter out some of the data before I get into the loop.

Here is how I reference the list:

```
SPList list = root.Lists[LISTNAME];
```

And I want to do something like:

```
var items = from li in list.items
    where li.field.Contains("value")
    select li;
```

Is this possible? I am not sure if the standard namespace System.Linq can be used with SharePoint.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *need* to use Linq, you could go with [SPMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538255(v=office.14).aspx). But you can expect better performance by using CAML queries, like this:

```
SPWeb   web   = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList  list  = web.Lists[LISTNAME];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery
{
    Query = @"<Where>
                 <Contains>
                    <FieldRef Name='Field' />
                    <Value Type='Text'>your value</Value>
                 </Contains>
              </Where>"
};
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can do something like:
    <Value Type='Text'>" + dynamicValue + "</Value>

Comment: Sure, just append a String.Format and sanitize your input.

Comment: What if I have a list item ID and would like to get a field text based on the ID?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge, you could use [`SPList.GetItemById`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyid.aspx), or in CAML `<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value type='Counter'>123</Value></Eq></Where>`

Answer (score 3):

You probably want the `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Linq` namespace, instead of `System.Linq`.  You can find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.linq%28v=office.14%29.aspx).  Microsoft also has some documentation on Linq to SharePoint [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535491%28v=office.14%29.aspx).